# transform map : add new key value pairs to existing map Java 8

Tags: java, stream

I'm trying to transform a `Map` by adding a new `JsonObject` key-value pair, if any of the map's `JsonObject`'s key contains the "-fragment" `String`.

```java
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = rootJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries) {
    if (entry.getKey().contains("-fragment")) {
        // apply function that gets fragment data and adds
        // jsonobject 
    }
}
```

Could someone give me an example of how to do this in Java8?

Comment: Can you add a description of what the `function` is intended to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this even without java stream by simply invoking the `foreach` method of the `Set` class to traverse all its entries. Then, check if the entry's key satisfies your condition and in that case apply your `Function`.

```
Function<...> f = /* ... my function implementation ... */
entries.forEach(entry -> {
    if (entry.getKey().contains("-fragment")){
        f.apply(entry);
    }
});
```

Instead, if you want to use java stream to return a brand new `Set` created by the application of your `Function`, then you could stream your `Set`, filter each entry in the same way you're doing in your loop, map each entry to apply your `Function` and then return a value (the `Function` returning value, the updated entry or anything else you need). Finally, use the terminal operation `collect` to collect your data
in a new `Set`.

```
Function<...> f = /* ... my function implementation ... */
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> result = entries.stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains("-fragment"))
        .map(entry -> {
            //applying your function
            f.apply(entry);
            return entry;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```